# jQuery ONLY hour and seconds countdown

Tags: php, jquery, timestamp, countdown, strtotime

I have a code not very professional but it does what i want :). The code is basically doing if shop open count for how long if closed count how long left form opening. Now i wanted to style it with jQuery Countdown but i cant find any to just count hours,minutes, maybe seconds. I was trying UNIX countdowns but dunno what i`m doing wrong. I would like to ask you fellow citizens of Stackoverflow to help me out with this.

This is my code ( Just don`t be haters :) )

```
date_default_timezone_set('Greenwich'); //Fixes my server location

$openingtime = strtotime('06:00'); //Opening time
$closingtime = strtotime('23:10'); //Closing time
$timenow = strtotime('now'); //Current Server Time
$twentyfourhours = "24:00"; //Hours in a day

//echo date('G:i', $openingtime); //Just texting
//echo date('G:i', $closingtime);
//echo date('H:i', $timenow);
//echo $twentyfourhours;// Testing ends here


$openingin = $twentyfourhours - $timenow + $openingtime; //24:00 - 23:20 + 6:00 = How long left for opening
$closingdown = $closingtime - $timenow; //23:10 - 23:20 How long left to close

//If current time value is bigger then closing time then display when the shop will re-open again
if (date('H:i', $timenow) > date('H:i', $closingtime)) 
{
  echo "The shop will be open in ".date('H:i', $openingin)." hours";
}
//If current time value is lower then closing time then display how long the shop will stay open
elseif (date('H:i', $timenow) < date('H:i', $closingtime))
{
  echo "The shop will be open for ".date('H:i', $closingdown)." hours";
}
```

Comment: [SzkolaHTML.pl](http://szkolahtml.pl) - That`s my testing ground

Comment: I also would need info because i have created anoter elseif stating if openingtime row is empty to show message sorry we are closed but it does not work it just starts countdown from 24 hrs

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have managed to found one but now if you will go to [My Testing Ground](http://szkolahtml.pl/day.php) You will notice that the seconds instead of starting countdown from 60 they start from 00,99,98,97,97 and all the way down :( dunno why its happening i`m attaching JS code`

var flipCounter = function(d, options){

```
// Default values
var defaults = {
    value: 0,
    inc: 1,
    pace: 1000,
    auto: true,
    tFH: 39,
    bFH: 64,
    fW: 53,
    bOffset: 390
};

var o = options || {},
doc = window.document,
divId = typeof d !== 'undefined' && d !== '' ? d : 'flip-counter',
div = doc.getElementById(divId);

for (var opt in defaults) o[opt] = (opt in o) ? o[opt] : defaults[opt];

var digitsOld = [], digitsNew = [], subStart, subEnd, x, y, nextCount = null, newDigit, newComma,
best = {
    q: null,
    pace: 0,
    inc: 0
};

/**
 * Sets the value of the counter and animates the digits to new value.
 * 
 * Example: myCounter.setValue(500); would set the value of the counter to 500,
 * no matter what value it was previously.
 *
 * @param {int} n
 *   New counter value
 */
this.setValue = function(n){
    if (isNumber(n)){
        x = o.value;
        y = n;
        o.value = n;
        digitCheck(x,y);
    }
    return this;
};

/**
 * Sets the increment for the counter. Does NOT animate digits.
 */
this.setIncrement = function(n){
    o.inc = isNumber(n) ? n : defaults.inc;
    return this;
};

/**
 * Sets the pace of the counter. Only affects counter when auto == true.
 *
 * @param {int} n
 *   New pace for counter in milliseconds
 */
this.setPace = function(n){
    o.pace = isNumber(n) ? n : defaults.pace;
    return this;
};

/**
 * Sets counter to auto-incrememnt (true) or not (false).
 *
 * @param {bool} a
 *   Should counter auto-increment, true or false
 */
this.setAuto = function(a){
    if (a && ! o.atuo){
        o.auto = true;
        doCount();
    }
    if (! a && o.auto){
        if (nextCount) clearNext();
        o.auto = false;
    }
    return this;
};

/**
 * Increments counter by one animation based on set 'inc' value.
 */
this.step = function(){
    if (! o.auto) doCount();
    return this;
};

/**
 * Adds a number to the counter value, not affecting the 'inc' or 'pace' of the counter.
 *
 * @param {int} n
 *   Number to add to counter value
 */
this.add = function(n){
    if (isNumber(n)){
        x = o.value;
        o.value += n;
        y = o.value;
        digitCheck(x,y);
    }
    return this;
};

/**
 * Subtracts a number from the counter value, not affecting the 'inc' or 'pace' of the counter.
 *
 * @param {int} n
 *   Number to subtract from counter value
 */
this.subtract = function(n){
    if (isNumber(n)){
        x = o.value;
        o.value -= n;
        if (o.value >= 0){
            y = o.value;
        }
        else{
            y = "0";
            o.value = 0;
        }
        digitCheck(x,y);
    }
    return this;
};

/**
 * Increments counter to given value, animating by current pace and increment.
 *
 * @param {int} n
 *   Number to increment to
 * @param {int} t (optional)
 *   Time duration in seconds - makes increment a 'smart' increment
 * @param {int} p (optional)
 *   Desired pace for counter if 'smart' increment
 */
this.incrementTo = function(n, t, p){
    if (nextCount) clearNext();

    // Smart increment
    if (typeof t != 'undefined'){
        var time = isNumber(t) ? t * 1000 : 10000,
        pace = typeof p != 'undefined' && isNumber(p) ? p : o.pace,
        diff = typeof n != 'undefined' && isNumber(n) ? n - o.value : 0,
        cycles, inc, check, i = 0;
        best.q = null;

        // Initial best guess
        pace = (time / diff > pace) ? Math.round((time / diff) / 10) * 10 : pace;
        cycles = Math.floor(time / pace);
        inc = Math.floor(diff / cycles);

        check = checkSmartValues(diff, cycles, inc, pace, time);

        if (diff > 0){
            while (check.result === false && i < 100){              
                pace += 10;
                cycles = Math.floor(time / pace);
                inc = Math.floor(diff / cycles);

                check = checkSmartValues(diff, cycles, inc, pace, time);                    
                i++;
            }

            if (i == 100){
                // Could not find optimal settings, use best found so far
                o.inc = best.inc;
                o.pace = best.pace;
            }
            else{
                // Optimal settings found, use those
                o.inc = inc;
                o.pace = pace;
            }

            doIncrement(n, true, cycles);
        }

    }
    // Regular increment
    else{
        doIncrement(n);
    }

}

/**
 * Gets current value of counter.
 */
this.getValue = function(){
    return o.value;
}

/**
 * Stops all running increments.
 */
this.stop = function(){
    if (nextCount) clearNext();
    return this;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------//

function doCount(){
    x = o.value;
    o.value += o.inc;
    y = o.value;
    digitCheck(x,y);
    if (o.auto === true) nextCount = setTimeout(doCount, o.pace);
}

function doIncrement(n, s, c){
    var val = o.value,
    smart = (typeof s == 'undefined') ? false : s,
    cycles = (typeof c == 'undefined') ? 1 : c;

    if (smart === true) cycles--;

    if (val != n){
        x = o.value,
        o.auto = true;

        if (val + o.inc <= n && cycles != 0) val += o.inc
        else val = n;

        o.value = val;
        y = o.value;

        digitCheck(x,y);
        nextCount = setTimeout(function(){doIncrement(n, smart, cycles)}, o.pace);
    }
    else o.auto = false;
}

function digitCheck(x,y){
    digitsOld = splitToArray(x);
    digitsNew = splitToArray(y);
    var diff,
    xlen = digitsOld.length,
    ylen = digitsNew.length;
    if (ylen > xlen){
        diff = ylen - xlen;
        while (diff > 0){
            addDigit(ylen - diff + 1, digitsNew[ylen - diff]);
            diff--;
        }
    }
    if (ylen < xlen){
        diff = xlen - ylen;
        while (diff > 0){
            removeDigit(xlen - diff);
            diff--;
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < xlen; i++){
        if (digitsNew[i] != digitsOld[i]){
            animateDigit(i, digitsOld[i], digitsNew[i]);
        }
    }
}

function animateDigit(n, oldDigit, newDigit){
    var speed, step = 0, w, a,
    bp = [
        '-' + o.fW + 'px -' + (oldDigit * o.tFH) + 'px',
        (o.fW * -2) + 'px -' + (oldDigit * o.tFH) + 'px',
        '0 -' + (newDigit * o.tFH) + 'px',
        '-' + o.fW + 'px -' + (oldDigit * o.bFH + o.bOffset) + 'px',
        (o.fW * -2) + 'px -' + (newDigit * o.bFH + o.bOffset) + 'px',
        (o.fW * -3) + 'px -' + (newDigit * o.bFH + o.bOffset) + 'px',
        '0 -' + (newDigit * o.bFH + o.bOffset) + 'px'
    ];

    if (o.auto === true && o.pace <= 300){
        switch (n){
            case 0:
                speed = o.pace/6;
                break;
            case 1:
                speed = o.pace/5;
                break;
            case 2:
                speed = o.pace/4;
                break;
            case 3:
                speed = o.pace/3;
                break;
            default:
                speed = o.pace/1.5;
                break;
        }
    }
    else{
        speed = 80;
    }
    // Cap on slowest animation can go
    speed = (speed > 80) ? 80 : speed;

    function animate(){
        if (step < 7){
            w = step < 3 ? 't' : 'b';
            a = doc.getElementById(divId + "_" + w + "_d" + n);
            if (a) a.style.backgroundPosition = bp[step];
            step++;
            if (step != 3) setTimeout(animate, speed);
            else animate();
        }
    }

    animate();
}

// Creates array of digits for easier manipulation
function splitToArray(input){
    return input.toString().split("").reverse();
}

// Adds new digit
function addDigit(len, digit){
    var li = Number(len) - 1;
    newDigit = doc.createElement("ul");
    newDigit.className = 'cd';
    newDigit.id = divId + '_d' + li;
    newDigit.innerHTML = '<li class="t" id="' + divId + '_t_d' + li + '"></li><li class="b" id="' + divId + '_b_d' + li + '"></li>';

    if (li % 2 == 0){
        newComma = doc.createElement("ul");
        newComma.className = 'cd';
        newComma.innerHTML = '<li class="s"></li>';
        div.insertBefore(newComma, div.firstChild);
    }

    div.insertBefore(newDigit, div.firstChild);
    doc.getElementById(divId + "_t_d" + li).style.backgroundPosition = '0 -' + (digit * o.tFH) + 'px';
    doc.getElementById(divId + "_b_d" + li).style.backgroundPosition = '0 -' + (digit * o.bFH + o.bOffset) + 'px';
}

// Removes digit
function removeDigit(id){
    var remove = doc.getElementById(divId + "_d" + id);
    div.removeChild(remove);

    // Check for leading comma
    var first = div.firstChild.firstChild;
    if ((" " + first.className + " ").indexOf(" s ") > -1 ){
        remove = first.parentNode;
        div.removeChild(remove);
    }
}

// Sets the correct digits on load
function initialDigitCheck(init){
    // Creates the right number of digits
    var initial = init.toString(),
    count = initial.length,
    bit = 1, i;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
        newDigit = doc.createElement("ul");
        newDigit.className = 'cd';
        newDigit.id = divId + '_d' + i;
        newDigit.innerHTML = newDigit.innerHTML = '<li class="t" id="' + divId + '_t_d' + i + '"></li><li class="b" id="' + divId + '_b_d' + i + '"></li>';
        div.insertBefore(newDigit, div.firstChild);
        if (bit != (count) && bit % 2 == 0){
            newComma = doc.createElement("ul");
            newComma.className = 'cd';
            newComma.innerHTML = '<li class="s"></li>';
            div.insertBefore(newComma, div.firstChild);
        }
        bit++;
    }
    // Sets them to the right number
    var digits = splitToArray(initial);
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
        doc.getElementById(divId + "_t_d" + i).style.backgroundPosition = '0 -' + (digits[i] * o.tFH) + 'px';
        doc.getElementById(divId + "_b_d" + i).style.backgroundPosition = '0 -' + (digits[i] * o.bFH + o.bOffset) + 'px';
    }
    // Do first animation
    if (o.auto === true) nextCount = setTimeout(doCount, o.pace);
}

// Checks values for smart increment and creates debug text
function checkSmartValues(diff, cycles, inc, pace, time){
    var r = {result: true}, q;
    // Test conditions, all must pass to continue:
    // 1: Unrounded inc value needs to be at least 1
    r.cond1 = (diff / cycles >= 1) ? true : false;
    // 2: Don't want to overshoot the target number
    r.cond2 = (cycles * inc <= diff) ? true : false;
    // 3: Want to be within 10 of the target number
    r.cond3 = (Math.abs(cycles * inc - diff) <= 10) ? true : false;
    // 4: Total time should be within 100ms of target time.
    r.cond4 = (Math.abs(cycles * pace - time) <= 100) ? true : false;
    // 5: Calculated time should not be over target time
    r.cond5 = (cycles * pace <= time) ? true : false;

    // Keep track of 'good enough' values in case can't find best one within 100 loops
    if (r.cond1 && r.cond2 && r.cond4 && r.cond5){
        q = Math.abs(diff - (cycles * inc)) + Math.abs(cycles * pace - time);
        if (best.q === null) best.q = q;
        if (q <= best.q){
            best.pace = pace;
            best.inc = inc;
        }
    }

    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
        if (r['cond' + i] === false){
            r.result = false;
        }           
    }
    return r;
}

// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric/1830844
function isNumber(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

function clearNext(){
    clearTimeout(nextCount);
    nextCount = null;
}

// Start it up
initialDigitCheck(o.value);
```

};`